# How to change the position of this navigation style?

Tags: html, css

Here is a link to a set of navigation style:

http://tympanus.net/Development/ArrowNavigationStyles/

Please scroll down  the page to the last style "Fill Path".

I want to change the position of the navigation arrows, pushing each of them more to the edge of the container.

In the line 924 of the `component.css` file, there is this rule:

```
.nav-fillpath a::before,
.nav-fillpath a::after,
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::before,
.nav-fillpath .icon-wrap::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 3px;
    height: 50%;
    background: #566475;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    outline: 1px solid transparent; /* for FF */
}
```

Clearly, I should change the "`left`" property here for the arrows to move. But when I change it for instance to `80%`, one arrow moves closer to the edge (which I want), while the other distances from its edge. How this rule should be edited for both arrow to be push closed to their adjacent edge?

Comment: Just decrease the width of `.nav-fillpath a` css class.

Comment: oh man thank you, I can set yours as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just decrease the width of `.nav-fillpath` a css class.

```
.nav-fillpath{
      width: 100px; /* decrease this width */
      /* other css properties */
}
```

To give the text some space from nav icons, give margin to sides to `.nav-fillpath h3`.

```
.nav-fillpath h3{
     margin: 0px 30px;  /* remove margin: 0px; */
}
```

Comment: This works (for `.nav-fillpath a` ?), but causes the text to be too close to the arrow when you hover it.

Answer (score 0):

You can chance `right` and `left` of `.next` and `.prev`:

```
nav a.next {
    right: -35px;
}

nav a.prev {
    left: -35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.nav-fillpath .prev { margin-left:-80px;}
```